# Trouble with this error while adding a dict to an existing key value

Tags: python, json

Code Including JSON File Code:
Python( Suppose To Append A New User and Balance):

```
import json

with open('users_balance.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)['user_list']
data['user_list']

data.append({"user": "sdfsd", "balance": 40323420})

with open('users_balance.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=2)
```

Json(Object The Code Is Appending To):

```
{
  "user_list": [
    {
      "user": "<@!672986823185661955>",
      "balance": 400
    },
    {
      "user": "<@!737747404048171043>",
      "balance": 500
    }
  ],
}
```

Error(Traceback Error Given After Executing Code):

```
    data = json.load(file)['user_list']
KeyError: 'user_list'
```

Comment: when you run `print(json.load(file))`, do you see the same json structure that is displayed in your post?

Comment: try 

`data = json.load(file)`

`print(data, 'ensure there is a key')`
`data['user_list']`

Comment: @JimithyPicker Invalid syntax it says.

Comment: so the data['user_list'] worked?

Comment: @cashcash I'm good lol sorry... what is displayed when you print that.

Comment: @MZ Says that it's invalid syntax:
                                
    data = json.load(file) data['user_list']
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @cashcash could you update your OP so that the indenting and syntax is correctly formatted?

Comment: The error is here:  data = json.load(file) (pointing here) data['user_list']

Comment: @cashcash are those on the same line? Make sure there's no extra white space

Comment: The line you sent me is invalid syntax is all that it's saying the space between 'json.load(file)' and 'data['user_list']' doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219525/discussion-between-cash-cash-and-m-z).

Comment: use a debugger to inspect the variables at each line of the program, one problem is the `['user_list']` in the reading of the json file

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
import json

with open('users_balance.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file) 

data['user_list'].append({"user": "sdfsd", "balance": 40323420})

with open('users_balance.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=2)
```